# match all strings containing only one '/' character

Tags: regex, grep

I have a very long file containing file paths, one on each line. I would like to retrieve a list of all directories listed which are only 1-level deep. As such, I would like to extract only those lines which have a single `/` in them:

I want: `./somedir`
I don't want: `./somedir/someotherdir`

Can I do this with grep and/or regular expressions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  That's pretty easy:

```
find . | grep -P '^\./[^/]*$'
```

... where obviously the 'find' command I'm using just to illustrate what you described.  The regex works as follows:

- `^` and `$` are anchors specifying (respectively) the beginning & end of the line.  All content must be between those two characters
- `\./` is a literal period followed by a literal forward-slash
- `[^]` is a character-class that disallows anything after the `^` and before the `]`
- The `*` after `[^/]` says to allow zero or more occurrences of that character class

You could also do it like this:

```
dosomething | grep -P '^[^/]*/[^/]*$'
```

This will allow only a single `/` on the line, in any position on the line (even first or last character).

Comment: As an aside, the example you gave with the `./` leads me to believe you're generating a list with find.  Assuming that's the case, you can do something like this:  `find . -maxdepth 1 (other conditions)`.

Answer (score 2):

@Brians solution works, this is a more generic one that doesn't need a `./` at the beginning:

```
grep -P '^[^/]*/[^/]*$'
```

For example:

```
/aa/somedir
test/somedir/someotherdir
somedir/otherdir

--> somedir/otherdir
```